# Informatica Power Center - override value for user defined workflow/worklet returning Null value

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Workflow varibale declared -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtc07.png)

Parameter File
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDlaz.png)

Workflow Session failed as per logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKKHa.png)
Why the value from parameter file which is TestFile001 not passed when workflow session is running?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share bit more from the log? Has the proper paramfile been read?